# Java garbage collection fine tuning : Maximum pause time goal

Tags: java, garbage-collection

From oracle [documentaiton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html#concurrent_mark_sweep_cms_collector)

**Maximum Pause Time Goal**

> The pause time is the duration during which the garbage collector stops the application and recovers space that is no longer in use. The intent of the maximum pause time goal is to limit the longest of these pauses. An average time for pauses and a variance on that average is maintained by the garbage collector. The average is taken from the start of the execution but is weighted so that more recent pauses count more heavily.
>
> If the average plus the variance of the pause times is greater than the maximum pause time goal, then the garbage collector considers that the goal is not being met.
>
> The garbage collector will adjust the Java heap size and other parameters related to garbage collection in an attempt to keep garbage collection pauses shorter than  milliseconds. By default there is no maximum pause time goal. These adjustments may cause garbage collector to occur more frequently, reducing the overall throughput of the application. The garbage collector tries to meet any pause time goal before the throughput goal. In some cases, though, the desired pause time goal cannot be met.

For CMS algorithm, Excessive GC Time and OutOfMemoryError.

***What will happen if the goal is not met for Maximum Pause Time?  Does it ignore the violation and continue as it is like goal has been met? Or throw some exception like CMS throwing OutOfMemory?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Java 8 [GC Ergonomic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/ergonomics.html) documentation, it says:

> "**This is interpreted as a hint** to the garbage collector that pause times of  milliseconds or less **are desired**."

The goal is only a hint, not a hard requirement.

If the GC cannot meet the goal, it just continues.  As [the same document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/ergonomics.html) says:

> "It is typical that the size of the heap will oscillate as the garbage collector tries to satisfy competing goals. This is true even if the application has reached a steady state. The pressure to achieve a throughput goal (which may require a larger heap) competes with the goals for a maximum pause time and a minimum footprint (which both may require a small heap)."

And this matches my experience.  I've never heard of an OOME or similar where the message says that the error is due to this goal not being met.

(Certain other things are hard requirements though; e.g. the maximum heap size, and the excessive GC time limits.  Those limits *will* result in an OOME if they are violated.)